# Reaction of Br2/KOH with succinic anhydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, halides

> What products will be formed when $\ce{Br2/KOH}$ reacts with the following compound in water at room temperature?
>
> [image: Succinic anhydride]

Here is what I think is possible:

1. $\ce{OH-}$ will take up the acidic hydrogen.
2. $\ce{OH-}$ can attack the carbonyl group.
3. $\ce{OBr-}$ can attack the carbonyl group.
4. $\ce{Br+}$ can attack the lone pair of the doubly bonded oxygen and break the carbonyl bond.

Comment: Your first event ($\alpha$-deprotonation) is highly possible.

Comment: Succinic anhydride hydrolyzes readily to give succinic acid: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinic_anhydride

Comment: so you are saying that $Br_2$ will not participate in the reaction.